# a mutable type inside an immutable container

Tags: python, list, tuples, immutability, mutable

I'm a bit confused about modifying tuple members.  The following doesn't work:

```
>>> thing = (['a'],)
>>> thing[0] = ['b']
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> thing
(['a'],)
```

But this does work:

```
>>> thing[0][0] = 'b'
>>> thing
(['b'],)
```

Also works:

```
>>> thing[0].append('c')
>>> thing
(['b', 'c'],)
```

**Doesn't work, and works** (huh?!):

```
>>> thing[0] += 'd'
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> thing
(['b', 'c', 'd'],)
```

Seemingly equivalent to previous, but works:

```
>>> e = thing[0]
>>> e += 'e'
>>> thing
(['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],)
```

So what exactly are the rules of the game, when you can and can't modify something inside a tuple? It seems to be more like prohibition of using the assignment operator for tuple members, but the last two cases are confusing me.

Comment: *Note:* This is now in the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can **always modify** a mutable value inside a tuple. The puzzling behavior you see with

```
>>> thing[0] += 'd'
```

is caused by `+=`. The `+=` operator does in-place addition but *also* an **assignment** — the in-place addition works just file, but the assignment fails since the tuple is immutable. Thinking of it like

```
>>> thing[0] = thing[0] + 'd'
```

explains this better. We can use the [`dis` module](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) from the standard library to look at the bytecode generated from both expressions. With `+=` we get an `INPLACE_ADD` bytecode:

```
>>> def f(some_list):
...     some_list += ["foo"]
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (some_list)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
              6 BUILD_LIST               1
              9 INPLACE_ADD         
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (some_list)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

With `+` we get a `BINARY_ADD`:

```
>>> def g(some_list):
...     some_list = some_list + ["foo"]
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (some_list)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
              6 BUILD_LIST               1
              9 BINARY_ADD          
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (some_list)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice that we get a `STORE_FAST` in **both** places. This is the bytecode that fails when you try to store back into a tuple — the `INPLACE_ADD` that comes just before works fine.

This explains why the "Doesn't work, and works" case leaves the modified list behind: the tuple already has a reference to the list:

```
>>> id(thing[0])
3074072428L
```

The list is then modified by the `INPLACE_ADD` and the `STORE_FAST` fails:

```
>>> thing[0] += 'd'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

So the tuple still has a reference to the *same* list, but the list has been modified in-place:

```
>>> id(thing[0])
3074072428L
>>> thing[0] 
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Why isn't `thing[0] += 'e'` equivalent to `thing[0] = thing[0] + ['e']`, which would construct the correct list then lose it when assignment fails? That is, if it simplifies down to `.extend('e')`, why the `tmp` at all? Why not just `thing[0].extend('e')`?

Comment: @ChrisLutz: yeah, good point. You're completely right: it's not equivalent to `thing[0].extend('e')` but to `thing[0] = thing[0] + 'e'` like you suggest. I've fixed the answer to say that.

Comment: I still don't understand case I've labelled "Doesn't work, and works".   I would expect it to either a) work, with the list modified or b) raise exception and leaving the list unmodified.  How does it fail with exception AND modify the value?

Comment: @wim: I've updated the answer to emphasise what goes wrong: first `INPLACE_ADD` is executed (this mutates the list) and then `STORE_FAST` is executed (this fails when you try to assign to a tuple).

Comment: "Thinking of it like `thing[0] = thing[0] + 'd'` explains this better" - except that with that code, neither the tuple nor the list would change (the addition would create a new list, which then could not be assigned into the tuple). What actually happens is more like `thing[0].extend('d')` followed by `thing[0] = thing[0]` (which fails even though it "shouldn't" have any effect).

Answer (score 6):

You can't modify the tuple, but you can modify the contents of things contained within the tuple. Lists (along with sets, dicts, and objects) are a *reference type* and thus the "thing" **in** the tuple is just a reference - the actual list is a mutable object which is pointed to by that reference and can be modified without changing the reference itself.

```
( + ,)       <--- your tuple (this can't be changed)
  |
  |
  v
 ['a']       <--- the list object your tuple references (this can be changed)
```

---

After `thing[0][0] = 'b'`:

```
( + ,)       <--- notice how the contents of this are still the same
  |
  |
  v
 ['b']       <--- but the contents of this have changed
```

---

After `thing[0].append('c')`:

```
( + ,)       <--- notice how this is still the same
  |
  |
  v
 ['b','c']   <--- but this has changed again
```

---

The reason why `+=` errors is that it's not completely equivalent to `.append()` - it actually does an addition and then an assignment (and the assignment fails), rather than merely appending in-place.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace an element of a tuple, but you can replace the entire contents of the element. This will work:

```
thing[0][:] = ['b']
```