# What is this operator *= -1

Tags: python

I'm going through some Python activities and was given example code with this operator: `y *= -1`

I had a look through the [relevant Python docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), to no avail.

I know `y += 1`, for example, is short for `y = y + 1`. So is this `y = y * -1` y equals y times -1 maybe?

Closest thing in Python docs I could find is this: `x * y`: *product of x and y*

Is this it?

Comment: To find the relevant docs you would need to search for *augmented assignment*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the vast majority of the cases

```
y *= <expr>
```

is the same as

```
y = y * <expr>
```

but in the general case, it is interpreted as:

```
y = imul(y, <expr>)
```

which is then equivalent to:

```
y = y.__imul__(<expr>)
```

if `y`'s type overrides [`__imul__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__imul__).

This means that if `y`'s type overrides the *inplace* multiplication operator, `y*=<expr>` is performed *inplace*, while `y=y*<expr>` is not.

---

**EDIT**

It might not be immediately clear why the assignment is needed, i.e. why it is intrepreted as `y = imul(y, <expr>)`, and not just `imul(y, <expr>)`.

The reason is that it makes a lot of sense for the following two scenarios to give the same result:

```
c = a * b
```

and

```
c = a
c *= b
```

Now, this of course works if `a` and `b` are of the same type (e.g. floats, numpy arrays, etc.), but if they aren't, it is possible for the result of the operation to have the type of `b`, in which case the operation cannot be an inplace operation of `a`, thus the result needs to be assigned to `a`, in order to achieve the correct behavior.

For example, this works, thanks to the assignment:

```
from numpy import arange
a = 2
a *= arange(3)
a
=> array([0, 2, 4])
```

Whereas if the assignment is dropped, `a` remains unchanged:

```
a = 2
imul(a, arange(3))
=> array([0, 2, 4])
a
=> 2
```

Comment: Can you explain why is it interpreted as `y = y.__imul__(<expr>)` and not just `y.__imul__(<expr>)`?

Comment: See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__): " These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self)."

Comment: @wim there's then the infamous case of tuple modification `x = ([],)`, `x[0] += ['a']` `x`

Comment: @jamylak, yes! one of my favorites :)

Comment: Yep, I asked a question about that thing over a year ago... http://stackoverflow.com/q/9172263/674039

Comment: @shx2 I'm aware of that, which is a documentation if not explanation of why `__imul__` returns self (or something self-like).  But it does not explain why the assignment is done.  Why wouldn't `y.__imul__(<expr>)` work equally well as an interpretation here?

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps the AST greatly reflects the x86 and other integer multiplications machine instructions for performance (mul instruction has implicit source operand)?

Comment: I don't think that is a good example, because `int` doesn't define `__imul__` at all - the first case only works because `*=` falls back on `__mul__`.  So, this has nothing to do with whether `ndarray.__imul__` is implemented this way or the other.

Comment: Note the case where `a` and `b` are ndarrays of different shape.  Then `c = a * b` works but `c = a; c *= b` fails

Answer (score 3):

Yes that's correct. It just means multiply the left-hand value by negative the right-hand value. They're both arithmetic operators that differ simply by operation and expression binding, so I believe +/* are parallel everywhere else in overloads.

```
y = y * -1
```

Comment: It's not 100% identical, if `y` has side effects when evaluated (such as printing or modifying state). In `y *= -1`, `y` is evaluated once. In `y = y * -1`, `y` is is evaluated twice.

Comment: You mean the second evaluated from the equal operator? Nvm, you said modifying state. It's more apparent when dealing with items: `k[key] *= -1`