# Python mutable and immutable

Tags: python, immutability, mutable

I encountered to this example about python mutable and immutable:

```py
t = (1, 2, [3, 4])
t[2] += [5, 6]
```

This will raise error:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Until here I can understand the error because t is a tuple and tuples are immutable, but problem is `t` changed.

```py
print(t)
# Output (1, 2, [3, 4, 5, 6])
```

an other thing is attempt to change t[2] by using `append` or `extend` has no error and works fine.

```py
t[2].extend([7,8])
t[2].append(9)
print(t)
# Output (1, 2, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You can check this on the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: Although `t[2] += [5,6]` does alter the list in place, it *also* tries to write the result back to `t[2]`, as if you wrote `t[2] = t[2] + [5,6]`. That means trying to alter `t`, which is immutable.

Comment: @Chris_Rands You might say that, but in fact `+=` on a list _does_ modify the list in place.

Comment: @khelwood yes, sorry you're correct

Comment: I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172263/a-mutable-type-inside-an-immutable-container) would be a better duplicate, as it explains why the `+=` syntax raises an error while the `.extend()` doesn't, though [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) describes them as equivalent.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Good find.