# How to create a list of variable references in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, object

I am using Python 3. Suppose I have 2 variables and create a list containing the 2 variables

```py
a = 48
b = 42
arr = [a, b]
```

If I modify `a` then `arr` remains the same, this is because `a` is an integer, if it was an object, then the object in `arr` (that is technically a reference to the same object) gets updated. I want `arr[0]` to be a reference to the variable `a` rather than the value itself, so that if `a` is changed then `arr[0]` is changed as well. How do I do that?

Comment: You're trying to understand mutability. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172263/a-mutable-type-inside-an-immutable-container.

Comment: "a reference to the variable ``a``" There is no such thing in Python. Can you clarify what *behaviour* you want? Are ``a`` and ``b`` function locals or globals? Do you always need a list of "variable references", or also independent references? Do you need ``a`` and ``arr`` to appear "normal", or is a wrapping helper object acceptable?

Comment: `a` and `b` are globals, and I want them to appear normal @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. Since integer is immutable type, whenever you change integer value, you essentially create new object.

You can check this:

```py
>>> a = 48
>>> b = 42
>>> arr = [a, b]
>>> id(a)
263256736
>>> id(arr[0])
263256736
>>> a = 11
>>> id(a)
263256144 # it is a new object already
>>> id(arr[0])
263256736 # still points to the old object
```